# A difference between Mono.mapNotNull(....) and Mono.flatMap(Mono.justOrEmpty(....))

Tags: java, project-reactor

Being a novice to Project Reactor I'm trying to wrap my head around the documentation. However I still can't figure out if there any practical difference between the following (pseudo-)code:

```
aMonoObject
    .flatMap(value -> Mono.justOrEmpty(transform(value))
    .someOtherProcessing(...)
```

and

```
aMonoObject
    .mapNotNull(value -> transform(value))
    .someOtherProcessing(...)
```

given that `transform` is a transformation method which is declared like this:

```
@Nullable <T, R> R transform(T value);
```

The activity diagrams look quite similar in the [docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#justOrEmpty-T-), I'm not sure that I understand everything correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result will be the same but there is a semantic difference between the two. In your case, the `mapNotNull` is a better choice because it does exactly what you need: transforms the emitted value within the existing stream. You could use `Mono.justOrEmpty` if you wanted to start a new stream.

A similar question would be what is the difference between `Mono.just` and `map` operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifications!

Indeed `mapNotNull()` looks like a a better choice for my case.

But previously I have discovered some code [e.g. this one](https://github.com/eriknyk/webflux-jwt-security-demo/blob/b4f944d953453488bf27682600fa466647c34a42/src/main/java/com/github/eriknyk/webfluxjwtsecurity/configuration/security/support/ServerHttpBearerAuthenticationConverter.java#L31) which uses the `flatMap(Mono.justOrEmpty(...))` technique. So I started to doubt what method is more correct...

Comment: @user3159253 mapNotNull is a recent addition to Reactor, it's not widely used yet